# Evaluating naked expressions case-insensitively

Tags: r, rlang, nse

I'd like to create a function that checks if naked expressions are contained in a vector or not. That function should work independently of the case of the input data.

A simple solution to evaluate a variety of expressions is to use `tidyselect::eval_select()`. E.g. here's a dummy function that checks whether or not expressions are `a`, `b` or `c`.

```r
is_abc <- function(...) {
  expr <- rlang::expr(c(...))
  data <- rlang::set_names(letters)
  out <- tidyselect::eval_select(expr, data)
  names(out) %in% letters[1:3]
}

is_abc(a, b, z)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is_abc(c(a, b, z))
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The problem is that I don't think it's possible to make it case-insensitive without editing `tidyselect::eval_select()` (or using a special selection helper).

```r
is_abc(c(a, B, z))
#> Error in `is_abc()`:
#> ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> ✖ Column `B` doesn't exist.
```

Alternatively, I could use `rlang::enexprs()` to get a list of symbols that will then be converted to character type when changing the case or comparing to the vector:

```r
is_abc <- function(...) {
  exprs <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  tolower(exprs) %in% tolower(letters[1:3])
}

is_abc(a, b, z)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is_abc(a, B, z)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The problem now is that this won't work for more complex expressions since that will convert entire expressions to strings:

```r
is_abc(c(a, b, z))
#> [1] FALSE
```

Is there a simple solution to this problem so that I can have a function working in both cases, without depending on the case of the input?

For example:

```r
# desired behaviour

is_abc(c(a, B), z)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the whole thing in base R:

```r
is_abc <- function(...) {
  
  args <- substitute(...())
  recurse <- FALSE
  if(".recurse" %in% names(args)) {
    args <- args[-match(".recurse", names(args))]
    recurse <- TRUE
  }
  out <- unlist(lapply(args, function(x) {
    if(is.call(x)) {
      x <- as.list(x)
      if(!identical(x[[1]], quote(c))) {
        stop("is_abc does not know what to do with calls to function '", 
             as.character(x[[1]]), "'")
      }
      unlist(do.call("is_abc", c(x[-1], .recurse = 1)))
    } else as.character(x)
    }))
  
  if(recurse) toupper(out) else toupper(out) %in% c("A", "B", "C")
}
```

Testing:

```r
is_abc(a, b, z)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is_abc(A, b, z)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is_abc(c(a, b, z))
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is_abc(c(a, B, z))
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is_abc(c(a, B), z)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

is_abc(a, b, c(z, c, c(a, b, c(z, y, c(a, b, c)))))
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually considering something similar. Turning the vector expression into character and then removing the first element looks somewhat "shoddy" so I was hoping for a better way. Not sure there's a simpler solution though so I'll go for it for now. Note that `as.list(match.call())[-1]` works here but is usually a bad idea because it also captures other arguments passed to the function call. `eval(substitute(alist(...)))` or even `substitute(...())` are generally better choices.

Comment: @arangaca updated to incorporate your suggestions. The code will now only ever change symbols to characters one at a time, and will never convert call names to characters. It can handle arbitrarily nested calls to `c`. It could be modified to handle calls to other concatenator functions like `list` if desired.